# Create filters with GMail API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, filter, visual-studio-2019, gmail-api

I am trying to create a filter with the Gmail API, using C# in Visual Studio 2019, that checks if an email has an attachment and then adds to it the corresponding label. I already got that label's ID and here's my code:

```
FilterCriteria criteria = new FilterCriteria
            {
                HasAttachment = true
            };
UsersResource.LabelsResource.GetRequest getLabel =
                gmailService.Users.Labels.Get("myemail@gmail.com", "Label_6");
var gotLabel = getLabel.Execute();
var labelId = gotLabel.Id;

FilterAction action = new FilterAction
                {
                    AddLabelIds = {labelId}
                };
Filter filter = new Filter
        {
            Criteria = criteria,
            Action = action
        };
UsersResource.SettingsResource.FiltersResource.CreateRequest requestFilter =
            gmailService.Users.Settings.Filters.Create(filter, "myemail@gmail.com");
requestFilter.Execute();

UsersResource.SettingsResource.FiltersResource.ListRequest requestList =
                gmailService.Users.Settings.Filters.List("myemail@gmail.com");
// List filters.
IList<Filter> filters = requestList.Execute().Filter;
Console.WriteLine("Filters:");
       if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0)
         {
          foreach (var filterItem in filters)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("{0}", filterItem.Criteria);
         }
}
 else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No filters found.");
}
Console.Read();
```

After that I'm just trying to print my filters to see if anything's changed. And this is the error I'm getting at the line with the "FilterAction":

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Of course, the gmailService is created and the scopes are all correct.
*Disclaimer: I'm new in C#.*
What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you have exception. you should find which code-line throw it. and find in that line what is null.

Comment: @demo I know which Line is throwing the error, I just don't know why would this be null. There has to be something related to how the gmail API wants certain things to be formatted and I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: pls point to that line

Comment: When asking a question, it's good to include all the information you have, including which line the error occurs on.  Currently your question says "I have a problem somewhere in these 30 lines of code", YOU know which line it's on, but we don't.

Comment: pls check how you create `action` variable and how to initialize collection. it should be something like `new FilterAction
                {
                    AddLabelIds = new List<string>{labelId}
                };`

Comment: `AddLabelIds = {labelId}` that line looks dodgy, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Neil I am already pointing out where I am getting the error thrown at...

Comment: @Stefanos the "AddLabelIds" is supposed to only accept IList objects or, as read somewhere else, strings. So since the IList option I was adding wasn't getting accepted under any circumstances, I added that string "labelId" which it actually accepted. But nothing happens.

Comment: @demo thanks for the tip! that was the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `FilterAction.AddLabelId` is not automatically initialised by the `FilterAction` constructor, so you need to do it manually:

```
FilterAction action = new FilterAction
{
    AddLabelIds = new List<string>{labelId}
};
```